# Methods called before thread.sleep not being executed

Tags: java, animation

I'm trying to code a basic Java program that allows a simple composite shape to be moved by the user, and in it, I have a button (QuitButton) that is linked to a private QuitHandler class. When the quit button is clicked, I want an animation to play in the program window before quitting the program. I knew I would have to implement a delay in order for the user to be able to see the animation before the program quits, so I added a delay using Thread.sleep(1000) after the animation but before System.exit(0) is called. So my code looks something like this:

```
//in private QuitHandler class (class linked to button)
//An ActionEvent is handed to handle(ActionEvent event) as a parameter
//when the quit button is clicked
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    animation.animate();
    this.delay();
    System.exit(0);
}
private void delay() {
  try {
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  }
  catch (InterruptedException e) {
  }
}
```

Whenever I comment out this.delay() and System.exit(0), the animation I want to show plays just fine. And whenever I comment out animation.animate() and leave this.delay() and System.exit(0), whenever I press the quit button there is a 1 second delay and then the program exits. However, when I have all three (the animation, the delay and System.exit) commented in, the animation **doesn't** play and I only get the delay and the program exits.

My understanding of flow of control would lead me to believe that the animation should play before the delay is triggered, so I don't understand why the animation works on its own, but not when this.delay() and System.exit(0) are called after it. I looked up the Thread.sleep() method on JavaDocs and I didn't see anything explaining why my implementation of the method would cause previous methods to not be executed. My best guess is that there is something about the Thread.sleep() method that is causing the issue but I'm not sure what it could be.

Comment: what does the `animation.animate()` do? is this a separate thread?

Comment: animation.animate() calls a method from my Animation class on an instance of that class (animation). The animation just specifies that a new shape be created and added to the same pane as the rest of the animation. Specifically, my animation is of a face and the "animate" method just instantiates a new ellipse, gives it a location based on the current location of my animation, and adds it to the root.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Thread.wait` instead. I don't know how that animation works but maybe it's synchronized with the current thread. `Thread.sleep` keeps the thread's monitor while wait release it allowing other threads to run.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `handle()` method is performed on the UI thread the result of the `animate()` method is not evaluated until `handle()` method is completed. Therefore i'd suggest using [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and [TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) doing something like this ([taken from this example](https://www.baeldung.com/java-timer-and-timertask)):

```
animation.animate();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("Task performed after 1 second");
    System.exit(0);
  }
};
Timer timer = new Timer("Timer");
long delay = 1000;
timer.schedule(task, delay);
```

This way the delay will become asynchronous and the `handle()` method will complete, allowing the UI thread to draw the graphics.

Please let me know if it helps :)